# How to convert my RDD of JSON strings to DataFrame

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I created `RDD[String]` in which each `String` element contains multiple `JSON` strings, but all these `JSON` strings have the same scheme over the whole `RDD`.

For example:

`RDD{String]` called as `rdd` contains the following entries:
**String 1:**

```
{"data":"abc", "field1":"def"}
{"data":"123", "field1":"degf"}
{"data":"87j", "field1":"hzc"}
{"data":"efs", "field1":"ssaf"}
```

**String 2:**

```
{"data":"fsg", "field1":"agas"}
{"data":"sgs", "field1":"agg"}
{"data":"sdg", "field1":"agads"}
```

My goal is to convert this `RDD[String]` into `DataFrame`. If I just do it this way:

```
val df = rdd.toDF()
```

..., then it does not work correctly. Actually `df.count()` gives me `2`, instead of `7` for the above example, because `JSON` strings are batched and are not recognized individually.

How can I create `DataFrame` so that each row would correspond to particular `JSON` string?

Comment: you can use flatMap over your first RDD[String] so that each json shall be each row string in new RDD[String]

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Could you show it in the answer?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: I get `Char` if I do `flatMap`.

Comment: if you have a valid json you can directly read as val data = spark.read.json(input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the information you've provided in your question, following can be your solution :

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val str1 = "{\"data\":\"abc\", \"field1\":\"def\"}\n{\"data\":\"123\", \"field1\":\"degf\"}\n{\"data\":\"87j\", \"field1\":\"hzc\"}\n{\"data\":\"efs\", \"field1\":\"ssaf\"}"
val str2 = "{\"data\":\"fsg\", \"field1\":\"agas\"}\n{\"data\":\"sgs\", \"field1\":\"agg\"}\n{\"data\":\"sdg\", \"field1\":\"agads\"}"
val input = Seq(str1, str2)

val rddData = sc.parallelize(input).flatMap(_.split("\n"))
  .map(line => line.split(","))
  .map(array => (array(0).split(":")(1).trim.replaceAll("\\W", ""), array(1).split(":")(1).trim.replaceAll("\\W", "")))
rddData.toDF("data", "field1").show
```

**Edited**

You can exclude the fieldNames and just use `.toDF()` but that would give `default column names` from your data (like `_1` `_2` or `col_1` `col_2` etc)

Instead you can create a `schema` to create `dataframe` as below (you can add more fields)

```
val rddData = sc.parallelize(input).flatMap(_.split("\n"))
  .map(line => line.split(","))
  .map(array => Row.fromSeq(Seq(array(0).split(":")(1).trim.replaceAll("\\W", ""), array(1).split(":")(1).trim.replaceAll("\\W", ""))))

val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("data", StringType, true),
  StructField("field1", StringType, true)))

sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddData, schema).show
```

Or

You can just create `dataset` directly but you will need a `case class` (you can add more fields) as below

```
val dataSet = sc.parallelize(input).flatMap(_.split("\n"))
  .map(line => line.split(","))
  .map(array => Dinasaurius(array(0).split(":")(1).trim.replaceAll("\\W", ""),
    array(1).split(":")(1).trim.replaceAll("\\W", ""))).toDS

dataSet.show
```

The `case class` for above `dataset` is

```
case class Dinasaurius(data: String,
                       field1: String)
```

I hope I answered all your questions

Comment: Is it mandatory to pass column names `"data", "field1"`? I have 100 columns in my real data set.

Comment: While it seems to work, it is adjusted to 2 columns (fields). I my real data I have 100 columns (fields). How can I fit your solution?

Comment: @Dinosaurius, I have answered all of your confusions and questions.

Comment: Indeed I managed to solve the problem as follows based on your ideas, but without case class and it works: `val jsonStrings: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(input).map(_.split("\n")).flatMap(x => x)

      val result = sqlContext.read.json(jsonStrings)

      var df = result.toDF()`

Comment: @Dinosaurius, I am happy to see that my post helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't check it right now but i think this should work:

```
// split each string by newline character
val splitted: RDD[Array[String]] = rdd.map(_.split("\n"))

// flatten
val jsonRdd: RDD[String] = splitted.flatMap(identity)
```

Comment: Wjat is `identity`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function Basically `flatMap(identity)` means `flatMap(x => x)`

Comment: Hmm, `jsonRdd.printScheme()` gives me `root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)`

Comment: in fact when I run `jsonRdd.toDF().foreach(f => println(f))`, I get `[{"data":"abc", "field1":"def"}] [{"data":"123", "field1":"degf"}] ...`. It looks like each string was passed to an array, but I now need to convert each field into DataFrame's column.